# SqlAlchemy table inheritance and primary keys

Tags: python, mysql, inheritance, sqlalchemy, primary-key

I have an inherited table in SqlAlchemy which complains about not having a primary key. Oddly, the parent table has a primary key. Here is the situation:

```
Parent(Base)
    __tablename__= 'parents'
    id = Column(INT, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

Child(Parent)
    __tablename__= 'children'
    birthday = Column(TIMESTAMP)
    parentId = Column(INT, ForeignKey('parents.uid', onupdate="CASCADE", ondelete="CASCADE"))

    parent = relationship("User", backref=backref('CommandsQueued'))
```

Note that the parent table has a primary key, and that the child table is inheriting that. Despite this setup, I'm getting the following error:

```
SAWarning: Could not assemble any primary keys for locally mapped table 'children' - no rows will be persisted in this Table.
  self._configure_pks()
```

I don't understand why SA doesn't recognize that the table does have a primary key. Does anyone know what is going on here? Am I misunderstanding the inheritance behaviour of SA?

Comment: there is a conceptual flaw in this, in addition to what was discussed in the answer, namely that a parent can have multiple children, and thus they cannot inherit a primary key, which by definition has to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's just a minimal example, it doesn't make much sense for Child to be a subclass of Parent. I'd expect both to be subclasses of Person, or something like that. In that case, you might want to take a look at polymorphic identity too.

Anyway, SQLAlchemy inheritance doesn't work like that. In the way you declared, It expects that your `Child` class and table declares its own primary key because it's a separate table, but if you try to do that with the same attribute name, you'll get a conflict. Try declaring the base id column using `sqlalchemy.orm.column_property` and it should do what you expect.

So, do something like this on the Child:

```
id = sqlalchemy.orm.column_property(Column(INT, primary_key=True), Parent.id)
```

And it should work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks Pedro. I tried this suggestion by adding the following method to both classes:

        @declared_attr
        def id(self):
            return Column(INT, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
 but got an even more confusing error:

Implicitly combining column Parent.id with column Child.id under attribute 'id'

I don't understand why it would do this, because it shouldn't be combining orm objects at all. I also tried just putting the method on the parent, originally, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Weird. What happens when you declare the Child.id explicitly?

Comment: If I declare id on both the parent and child explicitly, I get the same error as in the above comment.

Comment: OK, that's what I expected. I think the real problem is using the same attribute name. Try changing the attribute name on Child. If that works, then try changing it to `id = sqlalchemy.orm.column_property(Column(INT, primary_key=True), Parent.id)`

Comment: Thank you Pedro! I assume based on the code that we are using the same column object for both classes, or something like that? This is definitely not an intuitive corner of SA.

Comment: Actually it's the opposite. We are explicitly mapping it to different columns, but using the same attribute name. This linked issue has a little more clarification on that: https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issue/3041/orm-primary-key-retreival-can-populate

Comment: Frankly, I don't think SA is intuitive at all, but it's incredibly powerful, that's why I like it.